# Updating with case in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

I want to update a column according to another column value.
for example, In Value column i have numbers between 0 to 1. 
I want to check values and if:

```
Values < 0.45  set ValueStatus=Bad
Values >=0.45 and values<0.55  set ValueStatus =SoSo
Values >= 0.55 set ValueStatus=Good
```

I wrote the query like this:

```
update table
   set ValueStatus=(case 
                      when Values<'0.45' then 'Bad' 
                      when (Values>='0.45' and Values<'0.55') then 'SoSo' 
                      when Values>='0.55' then 'Good' 
                      else Values  
                    end)
```

But i get this error :

```
Error converting data type varchar to float.
```

Type of Values is Float and ValueStatus is Nvarchar(50)

Thanks

Comment: i think you should remove '0.45' quotes 0.45 @RmanEDV

Comment: Doesn't change anything, i've tried that before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this (you were adding ' to the numbers and SQL takes them as varchar) :

```
update table
              set ValueStatus=(case when Values<0.45 then  'Bad' 
              when Values>=0.45 and Values<0.55  then 'SoSo' when Values>=0.55
               then 'Good' else Values  end  )
```

Comment: From my understanding ValueStatus should be updated to one of the following values: "Bad", "SoSo" or "Good".

Comment: yes, but comapring Values (wich is a float) to '0.45' (wich by adding ' is a varchar) causes an error becouse there type is defferent all i dide  is taking away that ' to make SQL get 0.45 as a float not as a varchar

Comment: Yes, but it still doesn't produce the results he is looking for.

Comment: I'm sorry, ignore my previous comment, please. It will produce the result he is asking for. The "Else" clause is not needed though!

Comment: its okey :) , but no need for else as he said that the values are awlays between 0 and 1 and the last condition take it from 0.55 and up ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58158/discussion-between-bruno-and-youness).

Answer (score 4):

I believe your problem is based on how the `case` statement determines the return type.  You can read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx).

The numeric types have a higher precedence than the string types.  With the `else values`, you have four clauses in the `case.  Three return strings; one returns a number.  The number trumps the types so it tries to turn everything into a number.

You can mimic this problem with:

```
select (case when 1=1 then 'abc' else 12.3 end)
```

Happily, you can fix this by removing the `else` clause which is not needed in this case.

Comment: +1 the quotation marks are not the cause of the issue like the other answers are claiming.  Either remove the 'ELSE', or replace it with a NULL or a string.